# Stream highWaterMark misunderstanding

Tags: node.js

After reading some code on Github, it seems like i misandurstood how the `highWaterMark` concept works.

On a case of a writable stream which would write a big amount of data as fast as possible, here is the idea i had of the lifecycle:

1) While the `highWaterMark` limit is not reached, the stream is able to buffer and write data.

2) If the `highWaterMark` limit is reached, the stream cannot buffer anymore, so the #write method returns false to let you know that what you tried to write won't be write (never).

3) Once the stream emits a `drain` event, it means that the buffer has been cleaned up, and you can write again from where you got "rejected".

It was clear and simple in my mind, but it looks like this is not exactly true (on the step 2), is the data you try to write really "rejected" when the #write method returns false ? Or is it buffered (or something else) ?

Sorry for the basic question but i need to be sure !

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> 2) If the highWaterMark limit is reached, the stream cannot buffer
>   anymore, so the #write method returns false to let you know that what
>   you tried to write won't be write (never).

This is false, data is still buffered, the stream doesn't lose it. But you should stop writing at this point. This is to allow backpressure to propagate.

Your question is addressed in the [`writable.write(chunk[, encoding][, callback])`](https://nodejs.org/dist/v5.7.1/docs/api/stream.html#stream_writable_write_chunk_encoding_callback) docs:

> This return value is strictly advisory. You MAY continue to write,
>   even if it returns `false`. However, writes will be buffered in memory,
>   so it is best not to do this excessively. Instead, wait for the
>   `'drain'` event before writing more data.

Comment: when the return value is true. the written chunk is buffered in where? still in node memory or somewhere else?

Comment: I just tried it with waiting for drain and with ignoring the false return value and in both cases node used 14MB memory. This return value appears to be useless. Do you have an example where there is a real difference in memory usage?

Answer (score 34):

> is the data you try to write really "rejected" when the #write method returns false ? Or is it buffered (or something else) ?

The data is buffered. However, excessive calls to `write()` without allowing the buffer to drain will cause high memory usage, poor garbage collector performance, and could even cause Node.js to crash with an `Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory` error. See this related question:

[Node: fs write() doesn't write inside loop. Why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37579605/node-fs-write-doesnt-write-inside-loop-why-not)

---

For reference, here are some relevant details on `highWaterMark` and backpressure from the current docs (v8.4.0):

#### [`writable.write()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.4.0/docs/api/stream.html#stream_writable_write_chunk_encoding_callback)

> The return value is `true` if the internal buffer is less than the `highWaterMark` configured when the stream was created after admitting `chunk`. If `false` is returned, further attempts to write data to the stream **should** stop until the `'drain'` event is emitted.
>
> While a stream is not draining, calls to `write()` will buffer `chunk`, and return `false`. Once all currently buffered chunks are drained (accepted for delivery by the operating system), the `'drain'` event will be emitted. It is **recommended** that once `write()` returns `false`, no more chunks be written until the `'drain'` event is emitted. While calling `write()` on a stream that is not draining is allowed, **Node.js will buffer all written chunks until maximum memory usage occurs, at which point it will abort unconditionally**. Even before it aborts, high memory usage will cause poor garbage collector performance and high [RSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resident_set_size) (which is not typically released back to the system, even after the memory is no longer required).

#### [Backpressuring in Streams](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/backpressuring-in-streams/)

> In any scenario where the data buffer has exceeded the `highWaterMark` or the write queue is currently busy, `.write()` will return `false`.
>
> When a `false` value is returned, the backpressure system kicks in. It will pause the incoming `Readable` stream from sending any data and wait until the consumer is ready again. Once the data buffer is emptied, a `.drain()` event will be emitted and resume the incoming data flow.
>
> Once the queue is finished, backpressure will allow data to be sent again. The space in memory that was being used will free itself up and prepare for the next batch of data.

```
               +-------------------+         +=================+
               |  Writable Stream  +--------->  .write(chunk)  |
               +-------------------+         +=======+=========+
                                                     |
                                  +------------------v---------+
   +-> if (!chunk)                |    Is this chunk too big?  |
   |     emit .end();             |    Is the queue busy?      |
   +-> else                       +-------+----------------+---+
   |     emit .write();                   |                |
   ^                                   +--v---+        +---v---+
   ^-----------------------------------<  No  |        |  Yes  |
                                       +------+        +---v---+
                                                           |
           emit .pause();          +=================+     |
           ^-----------------------+  return false;  <-----+---+
                                   +=================+         |
                                                               |
when queue is empty     +============+                         |
^-----------------------<  Buffering |                         |
|                       |============|                         |
+> emit .drain();       |  ^Buffer^  |                         |
+> emit .resume();      +------------+                         |
                        |  ^Buffer^  |                         |
                        +------------+   add chunk to queue    |
                        |            <---^---------------------<
                        +============+
```

Comment: may i ask what tool do you use drawing this kind of diagram .

Comment: @Interaction: I copy-pasted the diagram from the Node.js documentation [here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/backpressuring-in-streams/#lifecycle-of-pipe).

Answer (score 4):

Any data you `write` to the stream will eventually be written even if the call returned `false` (and buffered in memory until then).

The `highWaterMark` option gives you some control on the amount of "buffer memory" used. Once you've written more than the amount specified, `write` will return `false` to give you an opportunity to stop writing. You don't have to though: if you don't stop, no data gets dropped, you just end up using up more memory (re-writing data would cause duplicates). And, as you mention, you can then listen to the `'drain'` event to know when it's time to write again.