# Building CLI tool in nodejs, child process output is not seen

Tags: node.js, pipe, nodejs-stream

I am Building a command line tool in node, and as part of this tool I need to execute commands that I have in my system.
The problem is that I don't get the piped output from the child process that I spawn in the program

The code that executed the child process:

```
import * as Child_process from "child_process";

export function asyncExec(command: string): Promise<string> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const child = Child_process.spawn(command, { shell: true });
    child.stdout?.pipe(process.stdout);
    child.on("error", (err) => {
      reject(err);
    });
    child.on("exit", (code) => {
      if (code === 0) {
        resolve(code.toString());
      } else {
        reject(new Error(`Process exited with code ${code}`));
      }
    });
  });
}
```

I have had another version of this code to try and make it work that uses exec

```
import * as Child_process from "child_process";

export function asyncExec(command: string): Promise<string> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const child = Child_process.exec(command, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(new Error(stderr || err.message));
      } else {
        resolve(stdout);
      }
    });
    child.stdout?.pipe(process.stdout);
  });
}
```

The stream of the stdout of the child process is not being printed, it is only printed after the promise has resolved

Why ? what can I do to fix this ?

Comment: Please see an example of reading child process stdout [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32872753/3592771). In a nutshell, you can listen to child process `stdout` events and read its data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix to the problem was doing the following:
`const child = Child_process.spawn(command, { shell: true, stdio: "inherit" });`

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the terminal command you are executing

`process.stdout` is a `readable stream` with an `highWaterMark` value of `16384` by default.

if the output is less then this size then you get all your response once the stream ends , else you will get it on every chunk of data

try for example a large output with a time out

`await asyncExec("printf 'k%.0s' {1..100}  ");`

`await asyncExec("printf 'k%.0s' {1..1000000000}  ");`

Further reading on streams highWaterMark
there is a great explanation  here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45905930/4267015

Comment: The actual fix for my problem was inheriting the stdio from the parent
`const child = Child_process.spawn(command, { shell: true, stdio: "inherit" });`